# Adding a stored procedure to a database

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures

If I create a database called `MyDatabase` and then wish to add a stored procedure to this database, do I have to specifically reference this database when running the SQL query for the stored procedure or is the stored procedure added to this database automatically?

Comment: ***WHAT database!?!?!?*** This is highly-vendor specific, and SQL alone is just the query language .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A stored procedure is an object that belongs to one database exctly. 
When you add the SP, it will be added to the database you are currently using.
To make sure you are running the current database, run this:

```
Use [MyDatabase]
GO
```

Comment: Thanks. If I am adding multiple SP, do I need a Use [MyDatabase]
GO statement above each one when running the SQL query?

Comment: Doesn't matter. In auto-generated scripts, it's there by default, to make sure you don't add the SP to the wrong database. If you are writing it yourself, you need it before the first one.If the answer was useful, please mark it as useful..

Comment: Isn't this exclusively for SQL Server? And even then, GO is not Transact-SQL, it's a keyword for the tools used in the background by SQL Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 1):

If you have selected your database in top left corner (Management Studio) MyDatabase the procedure will be created there. Else you can use the "Use" keyword I provide a little sample for you here.

```
Use MyDatabase 

create procedure hello 
as 
     select 'Hello World I'm a stored procedure'
go
```

And then run the exec command pointing to the name of the procedure

```
 exec hello
```

If you have selected another database ex master you could exec the procedure by pointing out what database to use.

```
exec MyDatabase.dbo.hello
```

And the dbo schema is the default schema in SQL.

This is for SQL Server.